# How does Cassandra Read Repair knows which data is latest?

Tags: cassandra, distributed-computing

Let's say the coordinator receives read query and the read Quorom is 2. One replica returned 0 and another 1. So how does coordinator knows which value is latest, so that it can write it back. I don't know how Cassandra does it. I don't think it is using system clock, how exactly it does can anyone please explain, not able to find in any documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Each write creates a mutation, that mutation has a timestamp. The timestamp is set by the client by default (for them to be idempotent) but can be created on the coordinator if not. That write time is based on the clock (microseconds monotonically so wont conflict locally) and used to determine the winner of a conflict (last write wins).